# How to insert text into a textarea when i know only the title

Tags: javascript, html, function, textarea, title

How to insert text into a textarea when i know only the title:

```
<textarea title="Napisz coś..." class="uiTextareaAutogrow input autofocus mentionsTextarea textInput" name="xhpc_message_text" placeholder="Napisz coś..." role="textbox" aria-autocomplete="list" autocomplete="off" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="typeahead_list_u_jsonp_3_10" aria-haspopup="true" onkeydown="run_with(this, [&quot;legacy:control-textarea&quot;], function() {TextAreaControl.getInstance(this)});" id="u_jsonp_3_11" aria-label="Napisz coś..." style="height: 63px;"></textarea>
```

Comment: Did my answer helped you? Please vote or/and mark as answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery you can do:

```
$("textarea[title='Napisz coś...']").val("test");
```

Working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/m67h9jge/

Hope that helps.